# Template shadow error with clang

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++, template-templates

As the comment in the following code snippet says, this is a workaround for a gcc 4.4. bug, which I probably should remove now. See [Template template parameters and variadic templates with gcc 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8514633/350713) for the background to this.

In any case, this gives an error on Debian Wheezy with clang 3.4.2-4, backported from unstable. This works fine with gcc 4.9 also backported from unstable (and 4.7) on Debian Wheezy.

```
// Workaround for gcc 4.4 bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8514633/350713
template <typename S, typename T,
      template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args> class C,
      typename... Args>
struct maptype
{
  typedef C<S, T, Args...> type;
};

int main(void){}
```

The error is

```
clang++ -o shadow.ocl -c -ftemplate-depth-100 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -ansi -Wextra -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function -Wc++0x-compat -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -std=c++11 -mtune=native -msse3 -O3 shadow.cc
shadow.cc:3:23: error: declaration of 'S' shadows template parameter
          template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args> class C,
                             ^
shadow.cc:2:20: note: template parameter is declared here
template <typename S, typename T,
                   ^
shadow.cc:3:35: error: declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter
          template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args> class C,
                                         ^
shadow.cc:2:32: note: template parameter is declared here
template <typename S, typename T,
                               ^
2 errors generated.
```

I see at least a couple of superficially similar questions on SO, i.e.
[Clang VS VC++:"error: declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20875033/350713) and
[C++ template that used to work in old gcc results in 'shadows template parameter' error in clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22056659/350713)
but is is not obvious to me whether they are a different problem or the same problem.

Clarifications appreciated. I don't write C++ regularly, and it has been a while since I looked at template template parameters.

Comment: The names in `template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args> class C` are superfluous. You may so write `template <typename S, typename T, template <typename, typename, typename...> class C, typename... Args> struct maptype`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for your comment. Is your version how one is supposed to write such code now? It is quite different from the examples I have seen.

Comment: @Jarod42: That would be worth an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names `S`, `T`, `Args` in the template template argument `C`

```
template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args> class C
```

are superfluous AND have the same names as the `S`, `T`, `Args` from `maptype`.
The fact that the names are identical produces the shadow error on clang.

So you may write

```
template <typename S,
          typename T,
          template <typename, typename, typename...> class C,
          typename... Args>
struct maptype;
```

or give different names (for documentation purposes as they can't be used)

```
template <typename S,
          typename T,
          template <typename S_Type, typename T_Type, typename... Args_Type> class C,
          typename... Args>
struct maptype;
```

Comment: Hi @Jarod42, thanks for the helpful reply. I have some followup questions. (1) Can you refer me to the standard, or something similar, preferably online, that addresses this issue? (2) If clang is correct to complain, why doesn't g++? Is this a g++ bug?

Comment: Oh, and if you can't refer me to something online, could you quote it in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I can't quote standard, I suggest you to ask similar question (You may create a shorter example just with `template<typename T, template<typename T> class C> class Test;`) with *language-lawyer* tag